# Unable to create object of base clas without default constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

As per my understanding, if we specify parametrized  constructor then compiler wont create default one for us and we need default constructor only if we are creating object without any arguments( If i have declared a parametrized constructor and created an object by passing parameters then compiler wont give error) . I have done the same thing in below code , i have created parametrized constructor and created an object by passing parameters but getting error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
    public :
            int var;
            Animal(int i)
            {

                    cout << "Animal Ctr " << endl;
            }
};

class Cat:public Animal
{
        public:
                Cat()
               {
                        cout << "Cat Ctr " << endl;
                }
};
int main ()
{
       Animal a(5);
       return 0;
}
```

above code works fine for me if i dont inherit base class but getting below error when i inherit Base class

DrivedMemberwithBasePointer_forum.cc: In constructor `Cat::Cat()':
DrivedMemberwithBasePointer_forum.cc:17: no matching function for call to`
   Animal::Animal()'
DrivedMemberwithBasePointer_forum.cc:4: candidates are: Animal::Animal(const
   Animal&)
DrivedMemberwithBasePointer_forum.cc:8:                 Animal::Animal(int)

As i know when i create object of base class ,compiler wont call drived class obejct but inj my above code it is calling. ., Can any1 please clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler would attempt to call default constructor of `class Animal` in member-initializer list of `Cat` constructor as you have not provided any constructor.

You can do this:-

```
Cat() : Animal(5)
```

OR

for getting value from user you should have parameterized constructor for `class Cat`.

Comment: This solution has created very basic doubt in my mind that is, i m not creating an object of drived class then why compiler is trying to call drived class constructor?

Comment: To construct a Cat you need to construct an Animal. This is always the case with Derived and Base classes. Every object of Derived class has an object of Base class.

Comment: @zoska Yes to construct a cat i need to construct an Animal this is fine , but in my code i m trying to construct "Only" Animal so why my compiler is looking into Cat constructor?
Also Can u give your view on last sentence of 'Oleksandr Mykolaichyk' reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created a constructor - you can do the following to solve the problem

```
Cat():Animal(5)
```

Comment: This solution has created very basic doubt in my mind that is, i m not creating an object of drived class then why compiler is trying to call drived class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

When you define constructor with parameters in class Animal compiler do not generate default constructor. If you want to create object of class Cat you can do the following thing's:

1. Create default construcor(without parameters) for class Animal or set default value for parameter of constructor like this Animal(int i=0).
2. Call parameterized constructor Animal in initializer list of Cat() with some value.
3. Change Cat() to Cat(int value) and call Animal in initializer list - Cat(int value):Animal(value)

About you errors:
Compiler analyze you code and can't see how to create object of class Cat even if you do not trying to create it in code. To resolve this issue, use the option from the list above.

Answer (score 0):

Even without creating an object of class Cat (as it's not a template nor forward declaration), compiler needs to have a full definition (even, when type is not used, it needs a proper definition).

When telling the compiler, that `Cat` is a derived class of `Animal`, the compiler needs to **know**, how it is supposed to create object of `Animal` type, when creating `Cat` object.
 Whether you use it or not, it doesn't matter.

As you have only default constructor of `Cat` type, and you do not specify, how object of `Animal` is created, compiler is looking for `Animal()` constructor. As it doesn't have one, hence the error.